# Are there other integer solutions to the equation $9x^3 -1 = y^3$ besides $(x,y) =(1,2)$ and $(0, -1)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does the above Diophantine equation have other integer solutions besides $(x,y)=(1,2)$ and $(x, y) = (0, -1)$?

Comment: This is a [Thue equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation) which can be solved algorithmically.

Comment: Following up on Jeremy's comment, see the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115063/solved-cubic-thue-equation

Comment: As a novice I would try factoring both sides of  y^3 - 1 = 9x^3, or maybe  8x^3 - 1 = y^3 - x^3, to see what that might say about x and y.  Gerhard "Likes Doing Diophantine Equations Old-style" Paseman, 2015.11.30

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Theorem 6.4.30 in Cohen's *Number Theory: Volume I* asserts: For each nonzero integer $d$, there is at most one pair of integers $(X,Y)$ with $Y\ne 0$ and $X^3+dY^3=1$. Apply this with $X=-y$, $Y=x$, and $d=9$, to see that that there are no more solutions. Theorem 6.4.30 is attributed to Skolem.

Comment: I think that settles it, thanks, will have a look at that !

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is another one: $x=0, y=-1.$